# In angular how to trim value in one way data binding

Tags: html, angular

In angular how to trim value in one way data binding, and can we do it at component.html not in typescript ?like below but didn't work :

```
<P>{{country.trim()}}</P>
```

Thanks

Comment: You can create custom `Pipe` and use that inside your `html` as `{{ country | trim }}`

Comment: @Kirubel, any example please ? I am not that familiar ! thanks

Comment: @JPNN, you can use directly, only you need use the "safe operator" to avoid errors when the variable was undefined `{{country?.trim()}}`

Answer (score 3):

you can use pipe for using the trim function in html only.

For pipe. please refer the following code:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'trimContent' })
export class TrimContent implements PipeTransform {

    transform(value: any) {
        if (value) {
            return value.trim();
        }
        return value;
    }

}
```

And now update your html code with the following line:

```
<P>{{country | trimContent}}</P>
```

Comment: I marked as not usefull the answer because only it's necesary use the safe operator to not get errors `{{country?.trim()}}`